# How to restrict width of grid container if there are few items but stretch to fill parent if there are many?

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a button that adds items to the grid when pressed, it looks like this at the moment:

[image]

As you can see, the grid container is stretched full width...but I want it to be the same width as the button and to only get stretched as more items get added, like so:

[image]

is this possible with CSS grid?

```js
document.querySelector('#add').addEventListener('click', function() {
 document.querySelector('.grid').insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<div class="item"></div>');
});
```

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(100px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 20px;
  
  background: #777;
  padding: 20px;
}

.item {
  height: 100px;
  background: white;
}

#add {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  
  background: #333;
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div id="add">+</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can approximate this using flexbox:

```js
document.querySelector('#add').addEventListener('click', function() {
 document.querySelector('.grid').insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<div class="item"></div>');
});
```

```css
.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  max-width:max-content; /* This will limit the container */
  
  align-items: center;
  background: #777;
  padding:10px;
}
/* This is a hack to limit the grow effect*/
.grid:after {
  content:"";
  flex-grow:999;
}
/**/
.item {
  height: 100px;
  background: white;
  flex-grow:1;
  width:100px;
  margin:10px;
}

#add {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  
  background: #333;
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div id="add">+</div>
</div>
```

Or you consider some JS since you are already using JS:

```js
var i=1;
document.querySelector('#add').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.querySelector('.grid').insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<div class="item"></div>');
  i++;
  document.querySelector('.grid').style.maxWidth=(i*100 + (i-1)*20)+'px';
});
```

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(100px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 20px;
  background: #777;
  padding: 20px;
  max-width:100px;
}

.item {
  height: 100px;
  background: white;
}

#add {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #333;
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div id="add">+</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need the items to be aligned vertically and I don't think flexbox can handle that...I guess I'll have to stick with the stretched grid container if there's no other solution :(

Comment: Yeah, guess that's the best way to go about it... thanks.